# Load and change content.php on the samepage.php instead of externalpage.php using Jquery or AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I want to load content on the same page instead of it going to an external page using AJAX or JQuery.  What is the best way to achieve this?

Here is a snippet of my external.php

```
$id = null;
    if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if (null === $id) {
        header('Location: gamerprofile.php');
    } else {
        $pdo = getDB();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM gamers where id = ?');
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $email = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
```

Is it ok to use the j query load function or is there a better way?

```
$("a.cRead").click(function() {
              $("#rpfsecTwo").load("read.php?id='.$row['id'].'");
       });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: WoHo Now that is a title. I am now so confused I have no idea `WhatPage.php` I am supposed to be thinking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery's `load()` is one of the good ways, and you can also use `$.get`:

```
$.get("read.php?id='.$row['id'].'", function(data, status){
        $("#rpfsecTwo").html(data);
    });
```

Comment: Ok i read about this function and I never thought about doing it this way...I want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use this when I want to include something on page without going to an external page. Not sure if its better or worse as they both do the same thing, but I've never used the .load() method.

```
var url = "read.php?id='.$row['id'].'";
$("#attach_frame").attr("src", url);
```